# A Level Discrete Mathematics Combination with Repetition Integer Solutions Question

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations

How many solutions are there to the equation:

$$ x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 = 21 $$

where $x_i$, $i = 1,2,3,4,5$ is a nonnegative integer such that $$0 \leq x_1 \leq 3, \quad1 \leq x_2 < 4, \quad \text{and} \quad x_3 \geq 15$$

If I think about each $x_i$, $i = 1,2,3,4,5$ as categories and $21$ ones to distribute between them, then I can use the combination with repetition formula. For example, when the only condition is that $x_i$, $i = 1,2,3,4,5$ is a nonnegative integer, I can get the answer of $12~650$ solutions by using the combination with repetition formula as follows.

$$
\qquad \qquad C(n + r - 1, n-1)
\\ \qquad \qquad \qquad =C(5 + 21 - 1, 5 -1 )
\\=12 \,650
$$

I don't know how to solve conditions on multiple variables at the same time. Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you try splitting it up into manageable cases? E.g. $0 + 4 + (x_3 - 15) + x_4 + x_5 = (21-15)$.

Comment: Normally, I would post an answer here.  In this case, I am not going to because between the OP's work and the already posted answer, the specific problem has been solved.  In general however, this type of problem has two distinct elegant approaches (1) [Stars and Bars + Inclusion-Exclusion] (2) Generating Functions.  For an example of a single problem where both methods were employed, see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3876263/find-the-number-of-triples-k-1-k-2-k-3-of-integers-such-that).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me help you along the way.

We know that $x_3\geq 15$. That means that if we define $y_3=x_3-15$ then we have $y_3>0$ and $x_1+x_2+y_3+x_4+x_5=21-15=6$. Use this trick again on $x_2$ (which has $1\leq x_2\leq 3$) and we have $x_1+y_2+y_3+x_4+x_5=5$ where our only constraints are that everything is a non-negative integer, and $0\leq x_1\leq 3$ and $0\leq y_2\leq 2$.

So if you count the cases now, using the method that you know, then you're almost done. All you need to do is make sure that $x_1$ and $y_2$ are $\leq 3$. If you calculate how many times we get $x_1>3$ or $y_2>2$, then subtracting that from the count should give you the final result.

Hope this helps! Good luck.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig you're right. I read that as $1\leq x_2\leq 4$. I'll edit the answer.